# which namespace is need to add for mathematical functions like sin, asin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need to calculate the following equation.which namespace is needed to add? I used `using System` but it's not detected my code and contains error

```
double n = arcsin(sin(0.1570) / cos(_savedPosition.Latitude));
```

Comment: Did you mean to use the `System.Math` API?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Isn't it the System namespace - [Math](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx) is the class in that namespace.

Comment: @PaulF Yes, it's in the System namespace in the core library. I said the `System.Math` *API*, not the `System.Math` *namespace*

Answer (score 1):

You correctly added the System namespace - but the methods you want are static methods of the Math class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx

Try this

```
double n=  Math.Asin(Math.Sin(0.1570) / Math.Cos(_savedPosition.Latitude));
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods you´re looking for are indeed within the namespace `System`. However you have to qualify the *class* that contains those methods also. This class is `Math` and all its methods are `static`. So write this:

```
double n = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(0.1570) / Math.Cos(_savedPosition.Latitude));
```

You could also use a [static using from C#6](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) upwards:

```
using static System.Math;
```

this will allow you to directly call the static members within `Math` without qualifying them:

```
double n = Asin(Sin(0.1570) / Cos(_savedPosition.Latitude));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Camilo mentioned. System.Math

Comment: See documentation - System is the required namespace, Matyh is the class within that namespace - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes this is more accurate